# Where can I read about import _{module name} in Python?

Tags: python

I've notice this. Example:

create an empty text file called for example ast.py

```
$ touch ast.py
```

run Python

```
$ python
>>> from ast import *
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> from _ast import *
>>> dir()
['AST', 'Add', 'And', 'Assert', 'Assign', ...]
```

ast is a python module. So... what's happening here? I tried with an empty os.py and didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special with `_xxx` modules except they are *private* (e.g. `_abcoll`) or *low-level* (e.g. `_thread`) and not intended to be used in general.

The `_ast` module is special, e.g.

```
$ touch _ast.py
$ python -c 'from _ast import *; print(dir())'
['AST', 'Add', 'And', 'Assert', 'Assign', 'Attribute ...
```

But this is **not** because of the leading `_`, but that `_ast` is a built-in module. Similar thing happens with the `sys` module.

```
$ touch sys.py
$ python -c 'from sys import *; print(dir())'
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'api_version', 'argv', ...
```

---

In Python `_ast` and `ast` are *two* separate modules. There is a line

```
from _ast import *
```

in the built-in `ast.py`, so importing `ast` will also bring everything from the `_ast` module in. This gives you the illusion that `_ast` and `ast` have the same content, [but actually `_ast` is a lower level module of `ast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html).

Comment: But here is happening something different. Import ast is importing the local one and import _ast is importing the global one.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `_ast` is **also** a module. There is no magic here. Also, `_ast` is a builtin module (i.e. a module that doesn't exist as a separate file, but is compiled in the interpreter itself), so it is always loaded and creating a file of the same same won't get rid of it.

And the reason why `_ast` will not be overloaded by a file, is that once a module is loaded, `python` will not look again at the files. You can find the list of all the modules currently loaded in `sys.modules`. And if you want a complete documentation about modules, look at the python documentation. Everything is specified, like here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html or here: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement